# Offspring of parents with different number of chromosomes

Tags: genetics, dna, population-genetics, chromosome

Many papers report that dog-whelks (Nucella lapillus) show a distinct chromosomal polymorphism between populations of 2n = 24 up to 2n = 36. Could somebody please tell me how many chromosomes the F1 generation of parents with (male) 2n = 24 and (female) 2n = 27 would have? What would happen to the three unmatched chromosomes?